# How to parse nested JSON in VBA

Tags: json, vba

I have a site that I need to connect to where I'd grab a JSON file and then parse out the information I need.  But I'm having a bit of a hard time as the data is nested... Could someone please assist? I'm using the VBAJSON library to try to parse this..

JSON file looks something like this:

```
{
    record: [
        {
            Name: "Bob",
            Created: "2020/06/18"
        },
        {
            Age: "52",
            TableName: "AGE"
        },
        {
            School: "Woodside",
            TableName: "School"
        }
        {
            Phone: "Iphone",
            TableName: "Phone"
        },
    ]
}
```

'this is an attempt to start getting the data and parse it but I'm lost...

```
Sub getjson2()
Dim hReq As New WinHttpRequest
Dim strURL As String, JSON As Dictionary

strURL = "testsite.com/abcd"

hReq.Open "GET", strURL, False

hReq.Send

Dim response As String
    response = hReq.ResponseText
    

Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, the Json you've posted is not valid. More specifically it's missing a comma right after the 3rd element of the array, there's a comma that shouldn't be there right after the 4th element of the array and it's also missing quotes from all keys. It should look like so:

```
{
  "record": [
    {
      "Name": "Bob",
      "Created": "2020/06/18"
    },
    {
      "Age": "52",
      "TableName": "AGE"
    },
    {
      "School": "Woodside",
      "TableName": "School"
    },
    {
      "Phone": "Iphone",
      "TableName": "Phone"
    }
    
  ]
}
```

Apart from that, I see you're using `VBA-JSON` parser so I assume you have added a reference to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library.

Having said all the above, parsing the json is fairly easy. Here's how to get the value of the `School` key for example:

```
Debug.Print JSON("record")(3)("School")
```

This will print `Woodside` in your immediate window.
You can get the rest of the values by adjusting the code accordingly.

**Note:**

I always recommend using the standard JSON format. However, If this is out of your control because that's how the response you're getting is formatted, there is a way to circumvent missing quotes:

```
JsonConverter.JsonOptions.AllowUnquotedKeys = True
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution available for that in Github.
https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

This solution is basically adding functions that convert to and from JSON.